# How common is it to be implanted with mind enhancing cybernetics in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

[Lobot](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lobot) and [Tseebo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tseebo) were both characters that had parts of themselves removed in order to become "more efficient".
In a universe where you can build a robot to do everything how common is it for other species to just go ahead and get half lobotomised in order to increase their mental capabilities?

EDIT: I'm not asking about Jedi here nor am I asking about replacement bodyparts (arms, legs etc. coz that is usefull and can be much, much better that normal human apendages.) I'm asking about the brain only.

Lobot and Tseebo were both perfectly fine and 100% sane prior to having the implants done. In both cases severe injury made the implants take over and make them "wierd".

Answer (score 1):

What one needs to understand is that the technology in STAR WARS what thousands of years more time than ours head. Even though this is the case, the technology when it comes down to body/mind enhancing / body repairing isn't perfect and isn't something commonly done.

To make two canon references:

(1) General Grievous who once was a Kaleesh warlord. An attempted assassination failed and he survived but to save him, he had to be transformed into a cyborg. By cyborg do I mean, everything apart from his inner organs, he was a robot. Even though this greatly enhanced his skills (Just see the four arms with rotating hands), the engineers whilst working on him didn't do anything to enhance his mental power while they were on it.

(2) Darth Vader who once was a human got locked down in his suit with an half-cybernetic body which was - source is the book: "The rise of Darth Vader" - far from perfect, even though its discussed this was also sort of punishment from Darth Sidious for his failure to kill Obi-Wan Kenobi. Again, no one seem to have bordered to enhance Darth Vaders mind. Else he would not have described himself as a wreck and they could have done something about the pain he always feeled and all the problems he seems to have with his new armour. The droids placed implants, that helped him hear and see and feel. But no direct mind enhancement has been done either.

So, going out from a canon point of view, I do not see mental enhancement in form of a sugerical modification as common, I just think the risks involved in such a thing are too big.

Comment: So, TL;DR: "Not common"?

Comment: Point taken. I still don't think its a desirable thing like a tattoo to have an enhanced mind if it involves the risk of being disabled or killed in the process. And in SW - Just see the fact that Vader could have exchanged his armour for a better version of it but refused because he feared to be killed in the process - it seems to be a dangerous process, hence why I stick to that its not common for have an enhanced mind if it isn't really NEEDED and the risk involved is to be taken under.

Comment: A brain implant vs a whole-body overhaul. Not really the same thing.

Comment: In addition, computers do not have a connection to the Force. This likely means that lobotomizing yourself for computational power reduces your connection to the Force. If you remember, Lobot and Tseebo weren't exactly... normal...